# Best way to initialize / addto Map values that are Lists in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I find myself repeatedly writing this code:

```
map[id] = map[id]  ?  map[id] + newListItem : [newListItem]
```

Is there a more succinct way to initialize the value as a List or add to an existing list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An alternative would be to use [`Map.withDefault`](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/07/groovy-goodness-map-with-default-values.html) like so (taking Ted's example):

```
def map = [:].withDefault { [] }
def id = 'foo'
def newListItem = 'bar'

map[id] << newListItem

assert map[id] == ['bar']

map[id] << newListItem

assert map[id] == ['bar', 'bar']
```

Comment: nice! I forgot about withDefault, that's perfect for this kind of case and I've now got some code to refactor :)

Comment: Most concise and also fastest! See my timing comparison in Kyle's post.

Comment: Note that the maps wrapped by `withDefault` of type `MapWithDefault` are not serialiazble.

Answer (score 3):

Using the elvis (?:) operator is slightly more succinct:

```
def map = [:]
def id = 'foo'
def newListItem = 'bar'

map[id] = (map[id] ?: []) << newListItem

assert map[id] == ['bar']

map[id] = (map[id] ?: []) << newListItem

assert map[id] == ['bar', 'bar']
```

Though if speed is important, Kyle's answer is a bit quicker as it doesn't do the assignment step (tested 100,000 loops on my machine, his is 1.36s and mine is 1.46s vs 16.54s for the original).

Comment: @virtualeyes [not quite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119282/best-way-to-initialize-addto-map-values-that-are-lists-in-groovy/6120617#6120617), it's possible to be more consise

Comment: @tim, true, I see your answer is the most concise. +1'd your answer. What will @Ted come back with? Love the myriad possible solutions in Groovy ;--)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a more succinct way, but an alternative that's not much better looking is this:

```
if (map[id]) map[id] << newListItem else map[id] = [newListItem]
```

Just for kicks I ran each syntax in a loop for 100,000 iterations:

```
def m = [:]
for (def i=0; i<100000; ++i) {
  //if (m['x']) m['x'] << 'val' else  m['x'] = ['val']
  m['x'] = m['x'] ? m['x'] + 'val' : ['val']
}
```

The time results for your syntax were:

```
real 0m45.367s
user 0m47.647s
sys  0m0.712s
```

The time results for this syntax were:

```
real 0m3.612s
user 0m5.920s
sys 0m0.252s
```

The results were consistent across several runs of each.  So I would say this syntax is definitely preferred.  I think the constant reassignment to the hash entry is what's slowing it down so much.

Comment: My timing roundup:

Original
real 2m4.903s
user 1m47.753s
sys 0m8.025s

Ted's
real 0m3.161s
user 0m3.308s
sys 0m0.329s

Kyle's
real 0m3.010s
user 0m3.023s
sys 0m0.323s

Tim's
real 0m2.697s
user 0m2.725s
sys 0m0.324s

Answer (score 0):

@Ted totally nailed it.

Just as an exercise, the curious/adventurous might try:

```
List.metaClass.onMap = { Map m = [:], id->
    if(m[id]) 
        m[id] << delegate
    else 
        m[id] = [delegate]
}
def id = 'foo'
Map m = [:]
List l = [1,2,3]
m[id] = l.onMap(m,id)
```

From then on anytime you have a Map containing list values, you can use List.onMap() to populate.

Answer (score 0):

You need Groovy 1.8 to use:

```
def map = [:].withDefault { [] }
```

This won't work:

```
def map = [:[]]
```